# beanstalk doubling every hour what would speed of inchworms need to be?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, word-problem

A beanstalk is continuously growing at a constant rate so that after one hour its length 
is doubled, after two hours it is four times the original length, after three hours it is eight 
times as long, and so one. (The growth is uniform: every part of the stalk grows at the 
same rate.) Two bugs start at a distance of one foot away from each other on the beanstalk 
and begin crawling towards each other at the constant speed x ft/hr (x is some number). 
For what values of x will the bugs meet?

Answer (score 1):

Since both inchworms are travelling at the same speed they will meet at a point that is 0.5 feet between them.  So I only have to consider one inchworm trying to get to a point 0.5 feet away.

The beanstalk grows according to $ l_b = 2^t $.  So the location of our inchworm over time will be $ l_i = 0.5 + 2^t - xt $.  We wish the worm to reach the middle so we can change that to being $ 0 = 0.5 + 2^t - xt $.  Rearranging $ x = \frac{0.5 + 2^t}{t} $.  This tells us how fast our worm must travel in order to meet up at time t.

I then used wolfram alpha to work out that the minimum value for x would be 2.20488.

Comment: great explanation ! where do u teach at ?

Comment: I don’t.  I work as a computer programer and also an expert in probilitliy.

Comment: so .5 is the begining distance of say inchworm traveling from the left ? thats for t=0 right ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: doesn't the inchworm have to travel over .5 feet after the first hour ? as In for t=2,3,4... the inch work has to travel faster to cover the increased distance ?

Comment: In the inchworm's frame of reference it travels over .5 feet.  However in an external frame of reference it only moves .5 feet.  Its like walking the wrong way on a travelattor.

Comment: I get that part , but shoud'nt the distance of beanstalk be 2^t-1? as the inchworm only needs to cover Half the total distance . for t=1 the total distance is 1 and one inch worm needs to travel half this , which is .5 feet or 2^(1-1)/2 =1/2 same goes for t=2 its then only 2 feet ( not 4 feet ) to reach the inch worm in middle

Comment: let me get this straight , considering the x axis the stalk and the point (0,0) the center of it with each worm at (-.5,0) and (+.5,0) respectively. at t=1 the stalk is now 2^1 2 feet. this would put inch worm 1 back to (-1,0) which means it must travel at 1 foot per hour to meet the other worm at (0,0) right?? then t=2 stalk is now 4 feet and worm is at (-2,0) meaning he must jet real fast at again 1 foot per hour to reach middle which he will since in first hour he already covered 1 foot. I don't get where the .5 plays in

Comment: Q the Platypus you said u were an expert in "probilitliy" ? whats that ?

Comment: A typo for Probability

Comment: I'm afraid this is incorrect, because it assumes that the distance that the inchworm has effectively travelled isn't affected by the growth rate. That is, the distance it needs to walk isn't simply the 0.5 plus the effective length of section of beanstalk at time $t$, but rather, some scaled version of the 0.5 (which isn't trivial to determine, because the distance it has "effectively" walked will also scale with the beanstalk).

Comment: @QthePlatypus Why is it 0.5 feet? Say a worm moves at small speed $\epsilon$. Take a snapshot 3 hours later. Now it has to travel at least $4-3\epsilon$ feet, no?

Comment: @GlenO your reasoning is sound.

Answer (score 1):

Say one worm starts at position $p_1$ climbing upward. If its position at time $t$ is $w_1(t)$, then we know it is accelerating just from the beanstalk growing. And on top of that, it moves with its own speed $x$. The differential equation this suggests is $$w_1'(t)=\ln(2)w_1(t)+x$$ with initial condition $w_1(0)=p_1$. This is a nonhomogeneous linear ODE. Its solution is $$w_1(t)=\left(p_1+\frac{x}{\ln(2)}\right)2^t-\frac{x}{\ln(2)}$$

The other worm is climbing downward, and similarly has position at time $t$ given by $$w_2(t)=\left(p_2-\frac{x}{\ln(2)}\right)2^t+\frac{x}{\ln(2)}$$ Note that $p_2=p_1+1$. We want $w_1(t)=w_2(t)$ to have a solution in $t$. That is: $$\left(p_1+\frac{x}{\ln(2)}\right)2^t-\frac{x}{\ln(2)}=\left(p_2-\frac{x}{\ln(2)}\right)2^t+\frac{x}{\ln(2)}$$ This simplifies to: $$2^t=\frac{2x}{2x-\ln(2)}$$ As time passes, the left side takes values in $[1,\infty)$. So it is required that $\frac{2x}{2x-\ln(2)}>1$ in order for the worms to meet at some time $t$. The numerator is automatically larger than the denominator, and the numerator is positive. So we only need that the denominator is positive. So we need $x>\ln(2)/2=0.3465\ldots$.

Comment: While certainly a valid approach (although I didn't double-check all reasoning), it might be a little overcomplicated for a question that is tagged "algebra-precalculus".

Comment: how do u get the w'(t) with ln2?

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss If movement only came from the beanstalk growth, $w(t)=2^t$. And then $w'(t)=\ln(2)2^t$. To make that into an autonomous differential equation (so $w'$ is written dependent on $w$, not $t$), substitute back to get $w'(t)=\ln(2)w(t)$. (Then, since the speed is this component plus something from the linear motion, add the constant $x$.)

Comment: ah so it was the derrivative of position function ( w(t)) which is 2^t .

Answer (score 1):

Motivated by Glen's comment to my other answer, here is an answer that avoids differential equations. View the scenario as the lower worm starting at ground level and not walking, while the upper worm walks with twice as much speed moving downward. [I am avoiding arguing why this specific scenario is equivalent to the posed problem because I find it hard to explain convincingly and clearly.]

Consider the worm who is moving downward. If its speed is just fast enough, then its height above ground will stay constant. It will be walking downward at just the right speed to counter the upward push from the growing bean stalk. So there is a special speed $v$ where this happens. The upper worm reaches the lower worm [who is staying put on the ground] precisely if it can overcome speed $v$.

The upper worm starts at $1$ foot off the ground. If it did not walk, its instantaneous velocity at that moment [from the beanstalk growth] would be $\left.\frac{d}{dt}\left(1\cdot2^t\right)\right|_{t=0}=\ln(2)$. [Or perhaps you avoid calculus althogether if you are studying exponential growth and there is some other way to calculate this speed as $\ln(2)$.] So the worm has to move downward with speed greater than $\ln(2)$.

Converting to the original problem where both worms move, the speed would need to be greater than $\ln(2)/2$, agreeing with my other posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clearly from physics classical mechanics area.
Let's apply definition of relative velocity to the problem.  [See here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_velocity) I apply it twice.

First, see the pic. 1-2 bug A is at rest($V_A=0$) and bug B has speed $V_B=2*x (1)$ relative to Bug A.

Second, see pic. 3-4 Bug B now has speed $V_{BR} = V_B-V (2)$ where $V=2^t (3)$feet/hour is beanstalk speed. Bug B $V_{BR}$ is relative to beanstalk, i.e. beanstalk is not growing anymore :) [image: pictures 1-4].
The problem now come to a simple one where Bug B needs to cover distance $S=1$ feet. So, $S= V_{BR}*t (4)$. Add equations (1-3) to (4)

$S = t*(2*x-2^t) (5)$ or

$x(t) = \frac{S}{2*t} + 2^{t-1} (6)$, replace S with 1

$x(t) = \frac{1}{2*t} + 2^{t-1} (7)$

Let's find the minimum of the function (7) or differentiate

$x^{'}(t) = -\frac{1}{2*t^2} + 2^{t-1}*ln{2}= 0(8)$  or

$t^2*2^t=\frac{1}{ln{2}} (9)$

(9) is [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2*2%5Ex*ln2%3D1) gives this result for $t=0.884124$ or

$x(0.884124) = \frac{1}{2*0.884124} + 2^{0.884124 - 1} (10)$

$x = 0.565532 + 2^{-0.115876}=0.565532 + 0.922822= 1.488354  (10)$